# How with copying file over the network

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, file-transfer

ALL,

I have 2 machines at home: one running Windows 7, one running Windows XP.
What I want to do is to copy some files from Windows 7 to Windows XP share.

So what I did was to share the folder on the WinXP machine and then got it IP address by running 'ipconfig'. Then on Windows 7 I successfully accessed this share from Windows Explorer (aka My Computer). However when I try to copy files from Win7 to WinXP I got "Access denied" error.

Now, I'm logged in on both machines with the same user id and I can successfully copy files in other direction (from XP to 7).

What is the problem? What do I check?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe problem here: In workgroups shares are accesed with credentials of local users. So when you try to access share from windows 7, computer uses current Windows 7 user credentials, which are unknown for Windows XP. Try to set share permissions of folder in WIndows XP to allow full access for Everyone group.